# Фигура инфографики

Tags: html, css3

Есть такая фигура в виде стрелки. Выполняю ее с помощью `clip-path` и псевдоэлемента с фоном совпадающим с общим фоном родителя:

```css
@import url('https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css');



.box {
  position: relative;
  height: 96px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 60px;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin: 2rem;
}

.num {
  width: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.num:after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  width: 60px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 85% 0, 100% 50%, 85% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 85% 0, 100% 50%, 85% 100%, 0% 100%);

  -webkit-transform: translateX(5px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(5px);
  -o-transform: translateX(5px);
  transform: translateX(5px);
}

.num-inner {
  width: 60px;
  height: 100%;

  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;

  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;

  -webkit-flex-flow: column nowrap;
  -moz-flex-flow: column nowrap;
  -ms-flex-flow: column nowrap;
  -o-flex-flow: column nowrap;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;

  -ms-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;

  align-content: center;

  justify-content: center;

  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 85% 0, 100% 50%, 85% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 85% 0, 100% 50%, 85% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.body {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 10.6px;
  line-height: 13px;
  padding: 10px 12px 5px 18px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
 <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="box bg-light">
        <div class="num">
          <div class="num-inner bg-success text-white">
            <span>01</span>
          </div>         
        </div>
        <div class="body">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores natus incidunt culpa facere, iusto minus nam doloribus suscipit voluptatibus delectus?

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="bg-dark row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="box bg-light">
        <div class="num">
          <div class="num-inner bg-success text-white">
            <span>01</span>
          </div>         
        </div>
        <div class="body">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores natus incidunt culpa facere, iusto minus nam doloribus suscipit voluptatibus delectus?

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Вопрос:** Можно ли выполнить данную фигуру без использования псевдоэлемента (чтобы не подстраиваться под каждый фон)? На случай если фон будет вообще рисунком, цифра должна находится на расстоянии от текста.

Answer (score 1):

Если я Вас правильно понял, можно сделать следующим образом. Пример будет немножко топорен, но суть должен донести. Обертка с `position:relative` и двое детей c `position:absolute`. Дети с `clip`, позиционка по `translate`. И оперировать останется только размером высоты и ширины элементов. Если нужно раздвинуть цифру и текст - меняем ширину родителя. Если нужно увеличить высоту элементов - просто меняем ее у самих детей. Ну и собственно пример:

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0
}


/*стили выше добавлены только для этого примера, в реальном проекте используйте normilize.css\reset.css*/

body {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
  background: #5C6BC0;
}

/*стили для body - косметика, важно то что ниже*/

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 345px;
}

.number {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #43A047;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(85% 0, 100% 50%, 85% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
  clip-path: polygon(85% 0, 100% 50%, 85% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
  height: 100px;
  width: 250px;
  background: #E0E0E0;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 5% 50%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 6% 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="number"></div>
  <div class="text"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: и так тоже пробовала, проблема такого способа в том что он еще и резиновый должен быть, а при ресайзе уголки почему-то начинают расходится

Comment: Конечно они будут расходится, ведь размер резиновый. И это решается медиа-запросами. Просто адаптируйте модуль и все.

Comment: Адаптировать будет проще, потому что при резиновых размерах `clip` постоянно будет гулять.